# Having problems with inner joins in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

A friend and I, are having some troubles with LINQ

We are trying to display a zipcode where the name of the country is found by a foreign key in the zipcode table.

our LINQ call is as follows

```
var Zipcodes = from p in db.Zipcodes
   join i in db.ISOes on p.Iso_id equals i.ID
   select new { Zip = p.Zip, name = p.Name, Address = p.Address, Country = i.Country };

return View(Zipcodes.ToList());
```

We where able to display the Zipcode table with the foreign key showing its own value, but trying to use this value to instead display the country name (which is found in the ISOes table)

We get a value cannot be null error (paraname = outer)

LINQ is a new technology to us, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

OBS:

We remade some of out code and are stuck at what we think is a different problem. we are going to make a new post about this. Sorry for the wasted time, though we learned alot :)

Comment: are you sure your `db.Zipcodes` entity is valid? Can you show the code for *just* getting the zip codes that works?

Comment: What is the type of db?  Is this Linq to Entities or Linq to SQL or something else?

Comment: A lot of the Linq To Sql questions involve 'JOIN' that are not neccesary because Linq can handle these for you if you defined PKs/FKs correctly. Are you sure the relationships are correct? When you start using LINQ you try to translate you sql queries literaly, it's generally not the right approach. Can you provide a diagram of your domain (dbml file if you use linq-to-sql)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same error parsing files into classes and querying those generic lists.  It turns out that one of my lists was empty (null).  Once corrected, all was well.  I suspect that the original poster's problem is that there was no data in a joined table.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just select

```
var zipcodes = from p in db.Zipcodes
select new { Zip = p.zip, ..., country = p.ISOs.Country}
```

That should work if your FK structure is ok

Comment: sry this still gives the same error where it says the parameter "outer" cannot be null

Comment: What is your PK/FK structure? Optional keys?

Comment: This is really strange. What SQL is sent to the database? Can you profile that?

Comment: @Adam Rackis No it does not, it will do a regular join if your FK structure is ok. If you would not select the country in the new and do a foreach you would get n+1 selects

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
var Zipcodes = from p in db.Zipcodes
                             join i in db.ISOes on p.Iso_id equals i.ID
                             into ISOs
                             from iso in ISOs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new { Zip = p.Zip, name = p.Name, Address = p.Address, Country = iso == null ? string.Empty : iso.Country };

        return View(Zipcodes.ToList());
```

Comment: sry this still gives the same error where it says the parameter "outer" cannot be null